# Recursive function to reverse find

Tags: c++, recursion

`char` is the recursive function. It's not supposed to have any l

Comment: Is this a homework question because who would want to do that recursively except as an exercise to learn recursion?

Comment: If you can't get started on your homework assignment, you should ask your instructor for help. They apparently haven't yet earned their pay for providing you an education.

Comment: Think about reasons for which you want to stop the recursion. Then think about how to will access each character during each recursive call.

Comment: It sounds like your professor is asking you to implement `strrchr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty straight forward recursive implementation. Sadly, it's not tail recursive though.

#### Full Implementation:

```
char *rfind(char* str, char ch) { 
     if (*str == '\0')
         return NULL; 
     char * pos = rfind(str + 1, ch);
     if (pos != NULL)
         return pos;
     if (*str == ch)
         return str;
     return NULL;
}
```

#### Base Case: `str` is a string of zero characters:

```
     if (*str == '\0')
         return NULL;
```

#### Recursive Call:

```
     char * pos = rfind(str + 1, ch);
```

#### Determine if we want the result of the remainder of the string, or the current position:

```
     if (pos != NULL)
         return pos;
     if (*str == ch)
         return str;
     return NULL;
```

Comment: Hi i'm kind of new to this recursion, but in your code, does it point to the last occurrence of ch or the first? It should point to the last occurrence according to my question. But still thanks a lot though!

Comment: @AnitejRao That's easy to verify. `(p - s + 1)` will tell you the position of the character returned.

Comment: My code returns a pointer to the last instance of `ch` in `str`. If it doesn't find `ch`, it returns `NULL`.

Comment: @AnitejRao - hint 1 - the first 3 steps spins to the 0 at end of the line before starting the search.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion does not use loops.

So if your function is named  rfind(...), then in rfind you must accomplish all 3 of the following items:

- terminate without finding -- determine that you have reached the beginning of str, then exit with nullptr
- terminate with find -- recognize 'ch' at some location in the str, then exit returning the  location (a char*)
- keep searching -- by recursively invoking rfind(...), and returning the value that the recursive invocation returns.

---

edit - Just for fun, here is a 3 parameter rfind I think is more readable

Note: no loops, and both exit cases, and tail-recursion.

```
// find _last_ occurrance of ch in str, starting at indx
char*  rfind(char*  str,  char ch, int indx)
{
   // Req 1: terminate when not found, return nullptr
   if(indx < 0)       return (nullptr);  

   // Req 2: terminate when found, return char*
   if(ch == str[indx]) return(&str[indx]) 

   // Req 3: continue search, return search results
   return ( rfind (str, ch, (indx-1)) );    // keep looking
}
```

[removed - 3 parameter rfind Usage]

---

edit - to complete this version, I offer the following.  The result includes

a) 2 parameter rfind,

b) tail recursion,

c) some test code

I present the following in a casual reader format.  You will have to add forward declarations or re-arrange the code appropriately to compile.

USAGE of test_rfind():

Note that test_rfind() has 2 parameters which are passed into rfind()

```
int t122()
{
    char str[] = "t123abcdefg*o4";

    size_t strSize = strlen(str);
    std::cout << "\n       strSize = " << strSize << "            " << (void*)str
              << "\n       01234567890123" << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strSize; ++i) {
       test_rfind(str, str[i]);
    }
    test_rfind(str, 'z');
    test_rfind(str, '0');  // digit '0'
    test_rfind(str, 'K');
    // ...
 }
```

test_rfind invokes rfind(), 
and also screens out null str and null tgt to provide feedback for test user:

```
void test_rfind(char* str, char tgt)
{
   do // not part of the recursion, not really a loop, just a test simplification
   {
      if (0 == str) { std::cout << "       str is null " << std::endl;  break; }

      // ===================================================================

      char* pos = rfind(str, tgt);  // 2 parameter invocation - see below

      // ===================================================================

      if (nullptr == pos) {
         std::cout << "rfind('" << std::setw(14) << str
                << "', '" << tgt << "') :           "
                   << "  char '" << tgt
                   << "' not found" << std::endl;
         break;
      }

      // else found
      std::cout << "rfind('" << std::setw(14) << str
                << "', '" << tgt << "') = "
                << (void*)pos
                << std::setw(20) << pos
                << "    last '"  << pos[0]
                << "' at indx: " << (pos - str) << std::endl;
   }while(0);
}
```

Here is your required 2 parameter rfind().

Surprise! it simply does some validations, then uses the existing 3 parameter rfind().

```
// two parameter
char*  rfind(char*  str,  char tgt)
{
   // pre-validation
   if (0 == str) return(nullptr); // one null check here, rather than 'inside' recursion

   // pre-validation - tbr: check range (0 <= char <= 127)
   // allow (0 == tgt): a char can be 0

   // now use the 'just for fun' 3 parameter rfind
   return ( rfind(str, tgt, strlen(str)) );  // use tail recursion
}
```

I have found that this kind of 'intermediate step' on the way to a recursion handles several pre (and sometimes post-) validations.  This allows keeping such things from complicating the actual recursive function.

The 3 parameter rfind() is near the beginning of this answer, and is used unchanged.

And guess what -- it provides a usually necessary function: finding the last target char in a string, BUT you can start the search anywhere in the string. This way, if your string has 2 of the tgt chars - you find the last ch using the 2 parameter rfind(), then find the tgt before that one by using the 3rd parameter (instead of shortening the str).

Note: C++ allows two functions to have the same identifier when their signatures are unique.  Thus both 2 param and 3 param version share the name "rfind()".

Results from test:

```
       strSize = 14            0xbff8f4bd
       01234567890123
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 't') = 0xbff8f4bd      t123abcdefg*o4    last 't' at indx: 0
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', '1') = 0xbff8f4be       123abcdefg*o4    last '1' at indx: 1
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', '2') = 0xbff8f4bf        23abcdefg*o4    last '2' at indx: 2
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', '3') = 0xbff8f4c0         3abcdefg*o4    last '3' at indx: 3
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'a') = 0xbff8f4c1          abcdefg*o4    last 'a' at indx: 4
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'b') = 0xbff8f4c2           bcdefg*o4    last 'b' at indx: 5
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'c') = 0xbff8f4c3            cdefg*o4    last 'c' at indx: 6
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'd') = 0xbff8f4c4             defg*o4    last 'd' at indx: 7
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'e') = 0xbff8f4c5              efg*o4    last 'e' at indx: 8
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'f') = 0xbff8f4c6               fg*o4    last 'f' at indx: 9
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'g') = 0xbff8f4c7                g*o4    last 'g' at indx: 10
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', '*') = 0xbff8f4c8                 *o4    last '*' at indx: 11
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'o') = 0xbff8f4c9                  o4    last 'o' at indx: 12
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', '4') = 0xbff8f4ca                   4    last '4' at indx: 13
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'z') :             char 'z' not found
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', '0') :             char '0' not found
rfind('t123abcdefg*o4', 'K') :             char 'K' not found
```

---

I have recently been very impressed with -O3 optimization on my recursive code.

- In some tail recursions, the compiler completely removed the recursive call and return, as evidence that stack-overflow did not occur, where when compiled at -O0, the executable always crashed.
- In at least one repeatable test, the resulting fully optimized recursive implementation was 50% faster than the corresponding fully optimized loop implementation.